How to avoid a variable from becoming a Series in Pinescript?
All kinds of variables in Pinescript seem to become a Series. Like even a local variable inside a method.
Dummy code
export type FooLib
    int    bar
    string baz

export init(int bar, string baz) =>
    FooLib.new(bar, baz)

a_getter_method(FooLib id) =>
    id.bar == 0

export a_setter_method(FooLib id) =>
    // result get's unintentionally a series
    result = a_getter_method(id)

    if result
        id.baz := "whatever"

    if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
        // i don't wan't this to be possible!
        log.info("{0}", result[1])

Usage example
foo_lib = init()
a_setter_method(foo_lib)

The issue is, that my real code has tons of variables, sometimes very long array. Storing each calculation result seems to be quite an overheap!

This "build-everything-as-Series" is a core tenet of Pine and I assume it is heavily optimized. Why this is an issue for you? I don't have knowledge on their compiler code but the simplest assumption would be if you don't postfix any of your variables or expressions with the [1] type index, even though the variable itself would be a Series type, it won't store past calculations as those are never used which the compiler can clearly determine from your source code.

A variable can also be made simple or const. However it won't work most of the time - only with primitive datatypes.
This won't work
type Foo
    int bar

simple Foo foo = Foo.new(0)

This works
simple array<int> arr = array.new<int>(10)

